# Is it possible to associate one product backlog with multiple projects?

Tags: agile, scrum, backlog, agile-project-management

I'm building two products. I am trying to build one backlog for a product with two  Projects. My first product is a web application and the other is a mobile application.

Is it possible to associate those two Project with one team and one Product? The owner with one Product Backlog / table of release?

How can I manage Scrum with those two projects with one team and one Product Owner?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice: Don't run both projects parallel on one Scrum Team. Start and finish the most important one (maybe only a MVP [1]) and then start the other.

Every parallelisation will decrease the Teams productivity [2].

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product
2. http://www.dailyinfographic.com/the-high-cost-of-multitasking-infographic

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Qualle we should not run both the projects in parallel with a single scrum team as it may result in low productivity.

Yes, you can take common Product backlog but it is not a preferred practice. In this case you need to have two different Scrum teams for each product. You have to build separate sprint backlog for sprint of each team. Or you can build both the products one after another with a single scrum team again with a single PB.

If priority of both the products is same then you are suggested to proceed with 2 scrum teams, separate team for each product with a single product backlog.